# Numpy Package uses all the available cores and slow downs the process

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

I am using numpy package in the linux cluster. The numpy package uses all the available cores in the system. As a result its slow down the performance (takes more time) and also the system wait time is too long. The Figure 1 (System usage) and Figure 2 (System wait time) highlight this issue.

I came to know that numpy uses the multithreaded linear algebra packages (OPENBLAS). Whether is it normal to have this issue?. I couldn't understand the problem.

[Usage of system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7GCA.png)

[System wait time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bWK2.png)

Comment: Using more cores usually means the process is faster, not slower. However, you can limit the number of thread created, and then have less cores used.

Comment: I agree that more core means the process should be faster, but in my case it was opposite. the system wait time is too long. I dont know why. On the other hand in my windows system, it does not have any problem.

Comment: `numpy` does link against libraries that multithread. You can control the multithreading through environmental variables. Find the library you're implementation is linked against to know how, for example for MKL: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/recommended-settings-for-calling-intel-mkl-routines-from-multi-threaded-applications.